# iframe height, dynamic content

Tags: jquery, iframe

i have an aplication that loads iframes as tabs (jqueryTabs) how can i set the iframe height to fit the content?

i know that i can create a function loke:

```
function fit(iframe) {
    iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

and call it onLoad but the problem is that my iframe will change his content using ajax so i need a wey to resize the iframe dynamicaly.

i was tinking in somthing like:

```
$(HTMLIFrameElement).ajaxComplete(function ()
{ fit(this)}
);
```

but it dos not work

*******EDIT******************
Afther Webberig answer, w shuld i do?:

use an each to iterate al iframes or pass a specific id?

each:
pros
easy to implement

cons
performance? (average iframes 3-4 max 100)

specific id
pros
performance?

cons
have to define and mantain specifics id for many iframes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only do this from within the page inside the iframe. Add this code after updating the content:

```
window.parent.fit();
```

Comment: but how can i applay this to a specific iframe? onload i use fit(this)

Comment: You can pass any variable you want... Try an id for example:
window.parent.fit("frame1");  Then you can use document.getElementById("frame1") to get the iframe